# Getting Duplicate Data on Response On Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in laravel in php. So it might be very silly mistake. I have song table and song categories table. I am trying to fetch all category with their respective songs. I have implemented larvel eloquent one to many relationship between song category and song.

Here is my code of fetching data:

```
 public function getSongCategoriesWithSongs(){

     $json_array = array();
    $song_categories = SongCategory::all();

    foreach ($song_categories as $item) {
        # code...
        $json = [];
        $json['category'] = $item;
        $json['songs'] = $item->songs;
        array_push($json_array,$json);
    }

    return $json_array;
}
```

Here is response:

```
[{
    "category": {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Rock",
        "created_at": "2020-12-20T02:58:32.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-12-20T02:58:32.000000Z",
        "songs": [{
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Mere Mehboob",
            "thumbnail": "https:\/\/static.toiimg.com\/photo\/msid-71407401\/71407401.jpg?108311",
            "song_category_id": 1,
            "stream_link": "https:\/\/2u039f-a.akamaihd.net\/downloads\/ringtones\/files\/mp3\/mere-mehboob-qayamat-hogi-52150.mp3",
            "created_at": "2020-12-20T13:26:30.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-12-20T13:26:30.000000Z"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "title": " Taaron Ke Shehar",
            "thumbnail": "https:\/\/static.toiimg.com\/photo\/msid-71407401\/71407401.jpg?108311",
            "song_category_id": 1,
            "stream_link": "https:\/\/newmp3ringtones.net\/assets\/sass\/Ringtones\/TaaronKeSheharRingtoneByNehaKakkarJubinNautiyal2145436126.mp3",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Bewafa Tera Masoom Chehra",
            "thumbnail": "https:\/\/static.toiimg.com\/photo\/msid-71407401\/71407401.jpg?108311",
            "song_category_id": 1,
            "stream_link": "https:\/\/newmp3ringtones.net\/assets\/sass\/Ringtones\/BewafaTeraMasoomChehraRingtoneByJubinNautiyal352778308.mp3",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        }]
    }
}, {
    "songs": [{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Mere Mehboob",
        "thumbnail": "https:\/\/static.toiimg.com\/photo\/msid-71407401\/71407401.jpg?108311",
        "song_category_id": 1,
        "stream_link": "https:\/\/2u039f-a.akamaihd.net\/downloads\/ringtones\/files\/mp3\/mere-mehboob-qayamat-hogi-52150.mp3",
        "created_at": "2020-12-20T13:26:30.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-12-20T13:26:30.000000Z"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "title": " Taaron Ke Shehar",
        "thumbnail": "https:\/\/static.toiimg.com\/photo\/msid-71407401\/71407401.jpg?108311",
        "song_category_id": 1,
        "stream_link": "https:\/\/newmp3ringtones.net\/assets\/sass\/Ringtones\/TaaronKeSheharRingtoneByNehaKakkarJubinNautiyal2145436126.mp3",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Bewafa Tera Masoom Chehra",
        "thumbnail": "https:\/\/static.toiimg.com\/photo\/msid-71407401\/71407401.jpg?108311",
        "song_category_id": 1,
        "stream_link": "https:\/\/newmp3ringtones.net\/assets\/sass\/Ringtones\/BewafaTeraMasoomChehraRingtoneByJubinNautiyal352778308.mp3",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
    }]
}, {
    "category": {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Soft",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "songs": []
    }
}, {
    "songs": []
}]
```

As you can see songs get repeated.

**UPDATE**

Solved using eager loading

```
 public function getSongCategoriesWithSongs(){
    return SongCategory::with('songs')->get();
}
```

But don't know why the foreach method not working.

Comment: Using eager loading ```return SongCategory::with('songs')->all()``` to load relationship

Comment: thanks..it worked using eager loading...but have to use get() instead of all()..all method showing undefined...

Comment: I am not test the code, if this code worked, glad to hear

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public function getSongCategoriesWithSongs(){

 $json_array = array();
$song_categories = SongCategory::all();

foreach ($song_categories as $item) {
    $json_array[] = ['category' => $item, 'songs' => $item->songs] ;
}
return $json_array;
}
```

Comment: getting only last category item..and still songs get duplicated

Comment: edited code also producing duplicate data..thanks for helping..but I solved the problem using eager loading

Comment: can you check i have edited the answer, i forget to add array to $json_array, if songs are still duplicating can you share your db structure and model?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you assign the same relation twice.

Each SongCategory already has a collection of songs inside.
So in your foreach block, you assign a category with $json['category'] => $item which will load all related songs and pass them to the final JSON object. And you duplicate this by passing the next item $json['songs'] = $item->songs to the same array. Default Laravel behavior will be to fetch all related objects and transform them into JSON.

I would suggest you to use Laravel resources to return JSON objects with exact shapes: [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources).
You can fix your code block without eager loading by removing $json['songs'] = $item->songs assignment.
Eager loading works because you passed all your objects only once.

Comment: thanks for answer..but i have tried without $json[songs] before posting on stackoverflow ..but not worked..that time I only get song category data no songs[] is attached to it....i also have same thought like you described in answer,,so had to use eager loading